# How to check if all the item values of dict in python are same.?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dictionary`: keys are strings, values are integers.

For example:

```
data = {'a':100, 'b':100, 'c': 100}
```

I would like to check if all the item values in dict have same value or not? I can easily check which item value is the greatest but how do I check if all the values are same.?

Thanks

Comment: How about `len(set(data.values())) == 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `data.values()` and convert it to a `set`. If the length of the `set` is 1 then they are all the same.

Comment: why don't you provide the code like: `len(set(data.values()))==1`. This would increase the quality of your answer drastically

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 While code would be nice, your suggestion makes no sense. `values` instead of `items` and it works.

Comment: my bad, sorry :). Just wanted to emphasize, that the answer is right already, but it can easily be made more precise